# Infimum and bound of the inequality.

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, inequality, supremum-and-infimum

In a paper, I got the following inequality but can't understand why it's true. Any reference or explanation of the proof is welcomed.

$$\text{inf}_{\eta\in (0,1)}\tfrac{1}{\eta^d (1-\eta)^k}= \tfrac{(d+k)^{(d+k)}}{k^k d^d}\leq \frac{e^k}{k^k}(d+k)^k $$
I guess $d,k$ are constant and $e$ denote exponential. The paper doesn't mentioned it.

Answer (score 0):

I will assume that $d,k>0$.

The first inequality follows by taking $\eta =\frac 1 {1+\frac  k  d}$ and the second inequality follows from the fact that $(1+\frac k   d)^{d} \leq e^{k}$.

Comment: What is $d,k$ they are not constant? $\eta$ varies over $(0,1)$?

Comment: My best guess is that $d,k>0$. If you read the paper more carefully you might be able to verify this.  @GGT